# Getting the bootstrap-validated AUC in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, bootstrap, roc

In a paper by [Faraklas et al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23628224), the researchers create a Necrotizing Soft-Tissue Infection Mortality Risk Calculator. They use logistic regression to create a model with mortality from necrotizing soft-tissue infection as the main outcome and then calculate the area under the curve (AUC). They use the bootstrap method to find the "bootstrap optimism-corrected ROC area."

If I were to do this in `R`, how would it look like? The code I have been toying with looks something like below:

```
library(boot)
library(ROCR)

auc_calc <- function(data, indices, outcomes) {
  d <- data[indices,]
  # Using glm for logistic regression
  # Do I recreate the glm model for each dataset?
  fit <- glm(outcomes[indices,] ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=d, family=binomial)
  fit.predict <- predict(fit, type="response")

  # Using ROCR to calculate AUC
  pred <- prediction(fit.predict, outcomes[indices,])
  perf <- performance(pred, "auc")

  # Returning the AUC
  return(perf@y.values[[1]])
}

boot.results <- boot(data=my.data, statistic=auc_calc, R=10000, outcomes=my.outcomes)
```

Is this correct? Or am I doing something wrong - namely should I be passing in a glm model rather than recalculating it each time? As always thanks for the help.

Comment: Frank Harrell's `rms` package has functions for this task. Fit the model with `fit <- lrm(outcomes ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=my.data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)`, then use bootstrap validation with `validate(fit, B=1000)`. The output matrix includes the optimism corrected values, but only shows Somers' $D_{xy}$. However $\text{AUC} = 0.5 \cdot D_{xy} + 0.5$.

Comment: I would like to avoid using and relearning another package that would force me to rewrite what I have so far. Is there no way to do what I want using `boot` and `ROCR`?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: I emailed Harrell to ask why the validate does not output the C (auc) metric. Annoying.